# how to display 4 items each row in php

Tags: php, css

```
<?php


    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        $i = 0; 
        if($i % 4 === 0) { ?>
        <ul> <?php } ?>
            <li><img src="<?php echo $rows['images'] ?>" /></li>
                <p><?php echo $rows['brand'] ?></p>
            <?php if($i % 4 === 0) { ?>
        </ul>
            <?php } $i++; ?>
    <?php  }

?>
```

---

for css

```
ul{

display block
}
```

i think that the problem in css

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: `$i = 0; if($i % 4 === 0)` is always true. You probably want something like `for($i=0;mysqli_fetch_array($result);$i++){`.

Comment: your `$i` is always 0 place it outside the while and reset it to 0 when its on the last `$i % 4 == 0`. also im pretty sure `<p>` is not allowed inside a `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong here.

Firstly tables are built for this kind of of structure, that aside.

You should have an example of the HTML you want so that you have a goal to build your php towards.

But since i don't really know exactly what you want, and i usually don't do PHP i'l give it a shot.

Last time i did PHP i used echo a lot to avoid the tag mess. so i did the same here (resulting in what i think is more readable and more important debuggable).

The first thing i see is that your `$i` is inside the while loop, meaning it resets to 0 on each run. I moved that out of the loop and reset it on the last if test making each fourth.

Also the `$i++` can't be last, that would make your `$i=0`, `$i=4`, `$i=8`, etc. open and close the `<ul>` and there will be 3 unwrapped `<li>` between `</ul>` and `<ul>`.

The second thing is the `<p>` inside the `<ul>` (unordered list) but outside the `<li>` (list item) this is a no no. so i moved that inside the `<li>`.

```
<?php
$i = 0; 
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    if($i % 4 === 0) {
        echo "<ul>";
    }
    $i++;
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<img src=\"$rows['images']\"/>";
    echo "<p>$rows['brand']</p>";
    echo "</li>";
    if($i % 4 === 0) {
        $i = 0;
        echo "</ul>";
    } 
}?>
```

For the CSS try out the `display:inline-block`

```
li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This should be the result
http://jsfiddle.net/go16zspr/2/

I added the borders to the `<li>` so you can see what they really look like in terms of occupied space.

Hope this help. at least its some pointers.

Comment: Thomas Andree Lian thanks that helps me but i have a litle problem that the speech in <p> appears beside the photo and i need it under the photo

Comment: you can place a div around the image, that should make a frame around it forcing everything else bellow the div. like the p.

Answer (score 0):

The `$i = 0` should be outside of the loop as it will be set to 0 with each iteration the way you have it now.

Your css is wrong.

```
ul {
  display: block;
}
```

You should also put your `<p><?php echo $rows['brand'] ?></p>` in `<li></li>` tags if you want it inside of `<ul></ul>`